# Serve an HTML file including CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, server

I have this code in a file called index1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<script src="./testing.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./formats.css" />

</body>
</html>
```

This is my testing.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });
});
```

This is my formats.css file

```
body {
    color: blue;
}

p {
    color: green;
}
```

I'm hosting the html file on the local host with this file.

```
var http = require ('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var port = '2406';

function send404Response(response){
  response.writeHead(404, {"Content_Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Error 404: Page not found!");
  response.end();  
}

function onRequest(request,response){
  if(request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/'){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "index1.html")).pipe(response);

  } else{
    send404Response(response);
  }
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(port);
console.log("Server is now running on port 2406...");
```

When I run running.js in node it doesn't include any of the formatting or the Jquery when I go to the local host. I'm wondering why this is the case and what I can do to fix it.

Comment: side note: never include a stylesheet in the `body`. Put it in `head` to avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onRequest` function only handles 1 possible url "`/`".

You *COULD* add more `if` statements to serve the different files...

```
function onRequest(request,response){
  if(request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/'){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "index1.html")).pipe(response);

  } else if (request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/formats.css'){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/css"});
    fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "formats.css")).pipe(response);

  } else if (request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/testing.js'){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
    fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "testing.js")).pipe(response);

  } else {
    send404Response(response);
  }
}
```

But you might want to look into an HTTP server framework like express.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you may use `npm`'s [`http-server`](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server) in your root directory via installing locally, and then able to host your `index.html` and its dependencies. You don't need to extra code or maintain scripts to host your pages.